# How to split up the individual numbers of a date in a table

Tags: sql, date

I am taking my sql view that I am creating and inserting it into a form with mail merge so it can be automated. However i need to split up each value, for example 2020 goes to 2 0 2 0 and need to create an individual column for each of those numbers I tried using substring but that did not work

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the year from the current date using YEAR
2. Convert the Year to a string (e.g., varchar)
3. Pull the sub string using SUBSTRING

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(Year(GETDATE()) as varchar(4)), 1, 1) AS Y1,
           SUBSTRING(CAST(Year(GETDATE()) as varchar(4)), 2, 1) AS Y2,
           SUBSTRING(CAST(Year(GETDATE()) as varchar(4)), 3, 1) AS Y3,
           SUBSTRING(CAST(Year(GETDATE()) as varchar(4)), 4, 1) AS Y4
```

[image]